# What is the best symbol to put in a CSV file to replace missing values, when using it for an ETL job?

Tags: database, ssis, etl

I'm writing an SSIS job that has to read data from multiple csv files, sequentially.
Then it will have to insert the values into a SQL Server and Mongo database.
I am relying on a third party to provide the CSV files.  There will be millions of rows to process in total.

I've been informed that some of the values within some of the rows in the csv files will be missing, either the because the data is corrupt or null.

I need to tell them what to replace those missing values with in the csv file.

I'm considering two options:

- **Option 1:** leave the value completely empty, so that nothing appears between the two commas in the csv file.  For example, if
  value1, value2 and value3 had to appear but value2 was missing, the
  row would be rendered as: value1,,value3
- **Option 2:** A symbol, such as the minus - or plus + or underscore _

In my script, I want to look at each row and identify which values are missing and take certain action, based on:

- which values are missing (replace with some value)
- the number of values that are missing (if above a certain number, ignore the row)

I feel that option 2 would be superior for this because I can write something like

```
if(value == "+") 
{do x;}
```

If I tell them to put nothing (option 1) I feel like it will be harder to write code that can detect.  Or would SSIS interpret an empty value as an empty string? I.e., can I write:

```
if(value == "") 
{do x;}
```

I am a novice when it comes to these types of scripts, so I'm looking for advice from those are experienced in them: based on these requirements, what should I ask be inserted into the csv file to indicate values that are missing?

Comment: A purist would say leave it empty. I'd advocate for a known bad value that will never exist in your data. A plus/minus/underscore seems more probable than a tilde `~` or back tick ``` If you can deal with extended Ascii, a Thorn or something that doesn't exist on an American keyboard (or whatever country your data is sourced from) drops the probability of collision to a near zero

Answer (score 1):

From a business perspective: Don't modify another vendor's data without explicit approval from them and a strict rule for how and when to modify it, and to what values you can change it.

If you're using SSIS, load all the CSV files to your database and store it in staging tables exactly as it came over. Run your queries against the data set, ID records missing key values, remove them from the stage table, and store them in an error table. After each run, you can provide an output of all the error records missing data to the vendor. If the vendor gives you permission to update erroneous records, still keep track of which records were missing data, what the value came over as, and what value you updated it to.

Overall, this should accomplish 2 things. First, you can complete your ETL and pipeline stuff as needed. Second, and more important, you have documentation of how you are modifying the vendor's data in case anything goes catastrophically wrong and lawyers need to get involved.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.  The problem is I think I still need to tell them what to replace missing values with though, for the sake of the initial generation and delivery of the data.  If I don't, I risk having hundreds of thousands of different values that each represent different missing or corrupted values.  But if I give them a value (like +), then I could easily query my staging table for all missing values, right?